# using history api of Uber

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to build a process to consume history api of Uber to display details of the users trips on one of my webpage. Has anyone done this? 
I see that api definition on the UBER site 
https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v12-history

However this does not provide how to provide the driver id? How can i get to the history of one particular driver?

All i need is trip details for every driver - assuming the driver id is available.

Any request sample will actually help.

Comment: Potentially related, but for the rider history: https://github.com/ZLester/RideStats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uber currently does not have API endpoints that provide information about driver activity. This is something we are considering, but at this time we do not have any public plans for a release.

Thanks for your interest in the Uber API.  Follow @Uber_API and visit devblog.uber.com for updates and announcements.